# AWS load balander times out - PHP backend

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a PHP backend which connects over an API to our Java backend for some heavy duty number crunching.
Unfortunately this number crunching sometimes takes longer than 1 minute, and the AWS load balancer times out.

Do you know of a way to prevent this?

I was thinking getting PHP to keep pinging, or JQuery to keep pinging, or increasing the timeout of the load balancer, but I haven't been able to any of those.

Comment: Also, this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html says that we need to increase the idle timeout, but I cannot find such feature on AWS Beanstalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the ELB will timeout if no data is received for 1 minute.

Ideally this would be designed as a job, and you would just send status reports with ajax. If you can't do that, there are a couple of other options.

Send data, even if its just empty spaces. Keep in mind that php may use output buffering, and may not send any data unless the packet is of at least a certian size.

Contact AWS support to have the timeout for your ELB increased.

Comment: Agreed, ideally we would just poll until the job is done, but this is not an option in the short term unfortunately.

You mention send data, even if empty spaces, but I cannot see how I would do this since my PHP thread is tied up in a CURL call. Any idea?

Contact AWS support requires a premium account which we do not have..

Comment: @SebastienMarion If you don't have premium support, you may need to contact them via the forums.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to try this.